# node_modules not been installed

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, node-modules, npm-install

I am working on an Angular project "Album store product page" and I'm unable to install node_modules on my project directory. When I run "npm install", the installation will be initiated in my project root directory and node_modules will be added also, but when installation is completed the node_modules file disappears. I tried this also "npm install --legacy-peers-deps" but I got the same result. No error message was displayed and I'm using VScode on windows 10 for this project.

Please do you have any idea on how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Try to run `npm install --loglevel verbose` and share the output of `npm-debug.log` file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.